# How to add a new model (Video) to spree core associated with Product and its controller and a link to create it in Spree Admin layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

[image]

I want to add the last link video to Spree Admin panel under Product.
How I could go ahead and make this feature.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can create a spree extension or use one of your already existing extensions. In the extension's `models/spree` directory create a model file `video.rb`.

```
module Spree
  class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  #Add your active record associations
  #validations and model methods

  end
end
```

You then have to decorate `Spree Core` models affected by your new video model. For example your `Spree Product` model.
In your extension's `models/spree` directory create a product model decorator `product_decorator.rb`.

```
module Spree
  Product.class_eval do
  #your video association with the product. e.g
  has_one :video
  end
end
```

You can do this for any other spree core models associated with your video model.

In your extension's `controllers/spree/admin`you have to create `videos_controller.rb`. I suggest you take a look at [spree backend images_controller](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/images_controller.rb) for directions on how you can add this controller. If you plan to upload the videos to your application, you might need an `audio/video` transcoder such as [paperclip-av-transcoder](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder).

You will also have to deface `spree/backend/app/views/spree/admin/products/new.html.erb`  and `spree/backend/app/views/spree/admin/products/edit.html.erb` to add the video addition and removal functionalities. I do not know the structure and complexity of your application and therefore this is not a definite answer but a direction on how you can achieve what you want.

`

Comment: Thank you @Optimus for your quick response. I am newbie in spree and I just created a store using spree and I just want to add one more option in Product (like Image) the Video so that I can get the same behavior as Image for the product (like I can add multiple videos, edit them, list them and they all are associated with the current Product ), I find your detail ans very helpful,so I have to create a extension to add video to product, there is no alternate of this? Im little confuse on this how my extension will follow the spree admin flow for the product.
meanwhile thanks for your time

Comment: Extensions are the only way to customize your application without polluting spree core modules. They are important as they ease the process of upgrading from one spree version to another. If you are unfamiliar with spree extensions, I would suggest you go through [Spree developer guides on extensions](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/extensions_tutorial.html).